# Using the tr command to change a single word into uppercase

Tags: linux, bash, tr

I'm having difficulty interpreting the `tr --help`.

I know that

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <inputfile
```

turns all the characters in the file into uppercase

How do I turn a single word into uppercase?

I am not limited to using tr. I am looking for a way to scan a file (or input) for a set sequence for letters and then once it finds a match to turn them into uppercase letters.

Comment: how do you define the word? By it's position on the line or something else/

Comment: A set sequence of characters is how I would define word

Comment: `tr` doesn't do "single word". Define the problem further.

Answer (score 1):

Can `sed` solve your problem?

```
sed 's/sequence/SEQUENCE/g' < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ghost` is the word you are looking to upper-case, the following might do the trick. Here `\<` and `\>` represent word-boundaries. `\(` and `\)` delineate the capture group and `\U` upper-cases the captured group `\1`

```
sed 's/\(\<ghost\>\)/\U\1/g'
```